# The relation between GCD/LCM of 3 polynomials and the factors decomposition?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it  true that : the GCD of 3 polynomials is the product of the common factors (after factorization) of the these 3 polynomials ?

and the LCM of 3 polynomials is the product of all the common factors of the 3 polynomials ?

Comment: Why don't you take some examples and check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a polynomial ring over a field as well as in $\mathbf Z$ (actually in any U.F.D.):

- The g.c.d. of two (hence any number of) polynomials is the product of the irreducible factors of each of them, with the *lowest* exponent. As consequence, only the common irreducible do appear in the g.c.d.
- The l.c.m. of two (hence any number of) polynomials is the product of the irreducible factors of each of them, with the *highest* exponent.

Example, as suggested by @amWhy:

$\gcd(x^2-1, x+1, x^2+2x+1)=\gcd\bigl((x-1)(x+1), x+1, (x+1)^2\bigr)=x+1$.

$\operatorname{lcm}(x^2-1, x+1, x^2+2x+1)=(x-1)(x+1)^2$.